# Plot multiple markers on leaflet and attach a click event to each marker which redirects to a new page along with the clicked marker information

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am developing a mobile application using jQuery mobile and leaflet.
I am using ajax to fetch marker data from the server and plotting the markers on the map dynamically. I am using a $.each loop to loop through each object returned as Json from the server and to generate markers.
I am appending anchor element within each marker Popup.  When the user click on the anchor element the current page will be redirected to a new page and information like lat, lon, stName and state will be passed to the next page using query string.

The code works fine it redirects the user to the new page with all the information, but the mobile browser takes a long time performing the redirect operation.
When I tried redirecting to a new page without the query string the redirect operation was quick.

Is there an efficient way to perform this redirect operation with the information on the current page?
Does anyone know why there is a time delay when the page redirect using query string?
Is there an bindClick event in leaflet?

The structure of meta_data is as below:

```
meta_data=[{elev:50, ll:[-90,29], name:"Baton Rouge"}, sids:[123,456,789], state:"LA"}, ...]

    $.each(meta_data, function(ind, meta_obj){
        marker=L.marker([meta_obj.ll[1], meta_obj.ll[0]]);
        click_element='<a href ="http://storm.srcc.lsu.edu/mobile/climatedata.html?stId='+meta_obj.sids[0]+"&"+"lat="+meta_obj.ll[1]+"&"+"lon="+meta_obj.ll[0]+"&stName="+meta_obj.name+"&state="+meta_obj.state+'">Click Here For More Data</a>';
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Station Name: </b>"+meta_obj.name+"<br />"+"<b>Station Id: </b>"+meta_obj.sids[0]+"<br />"+click_element);
        marker.addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: The delay is more likely the server taking longer to respond. You need to devise and run tests to determine exactly where the delay is happening. Only then can you think about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue due to size of query string you are passing. You can use localstorage might be it will reduce your time.

```js
localStorage.setItem('stId', meta_obj.sids[0]);
localStorage.setItem('lat', meta_obj.ll[1]);
localStorage.setItem('lon', meta_obj.ll[0]);
localStorage.setItem('stName', meta_obj.name);
localStorage.setItem('state', meta_obj.state);

// Redirecting to the new page
window.location.href = 'http://storm.srcc.lsu.edu/mobile/climatedata.html';
```